# Flattening JSON from BestBuy API using Pandas

Tags: python

I am having trouble flattening a nested JSON from the Best Buy API. I am trying to access the products section and then divide each of the categories into a column inside of a dataframe. I can get all this into one column in a dataframe but I can't normalize it, I keep getting a keyerror: 0. There is a column of integers on the left hand side of the dataframe.

Here is my code:

```
df.dropna(subset=['products'])  
df2 = json_normalize(df,'products', [['products','manufacturer'], ['products','modelNumber'], ['products','regularPrice'], ['products','name'], ['products','upc']], errors='ignore')
```

Here is an example of the JSON data:

```
{
   "from":1,
   "to":100,
   "currentPage":1,
   "total":169,
   "totalPages":2,
   "queryTime":"0.056",
   "totalTime":"0.123",
   "partial":false,
   "canonicalUrl":"/v1/products(manufacturer=\"Corsair\")?show=manufacturer,modelNumber,regularPrice,name,upc&sort=manufacturer&pageSize=100&format=json&apiKey=qiEJFL2kYvg1WQ4ZYA4mqUnp",
   "products":[
      {
         "manufacturer":"CORSAIR",
         "modelNumber":"CMSA8GX3M2A1066C7",
         "regularPrice":45.99,
         "name":"CORSAIR - 8GB (2PK x 4GB) 1.0GHz DDR3 SoDIMM Laptop Memory Kit - Green",
         "upc":"843591013857"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: how the df should look like?

Comment: Hopefully with the dict keys as the column headers and then the values as the row values.

Comment: Got it - give my code a try.

Answer (score 0):

The below should work

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{
    "from": 1,
    "to": 100,
    "currentPage": 1,
    "total": 169,
    "totalPages": 2,
    "queryTime": "0.056",
    "totalTime": "0.123",
    "partial": False,
    "canonicalUrl": "/v1/products(manufacturer=\"Corsair\")?show=manufacturer,modelNumber,regularPrice,name,upc&sort=manufacturer&pageSize=100&format=json&apiKey=qiEJFL2kYvg1WQ4ZYA4mqUnp",
    "products": [
        {
            "manufacturer": "CORSAIR",
            "modelNumber": "CMSA8GX3M2A1066C7",
            "regularPrice": 45.99,
            "name": "CORSAIR - 8GB (2PK x 4GB) 1.0GHz DDR3 SoDIMM Laptop Memory Kit - Green",
            "upc": "843591013857"
        }
    ]
}, {
    "from": 1,
    "to": 100,
    "currentPage": 1,
    "total": 169,
    "totalPages": 2,
    "queryTime": "0.056",
    "totalTime": "0.123",
    "partial": False,
    "canonicalUrl": "/v1/products(manufacturer=\"Corsair\")?show=manufacturer,modelNumber,regularPrice,name,upc&sort=manufacturer&pageSize=100&format=json&apiKey=qiEJFL2kYvg1WQ4ZYA4mqUnp",
    "products": [
        {
            "manufacturer": "CORSAIR99",
            "modelNumber": "CMSA8GX3M2A1066C799",
            "regularPrice": 45.9999,
            "name": "CORSAIR - 8GB (2PK x 4GB) 1.0GHz DDR3 SoDIMM Laptop Memory Kit - Green99",
            "upc": "84359101385799"
        }
    ]
}]
df = pd.DataFrame(x.get('products')[0] for x in data if x.get('products'))


print(df)
```